# Where to start in a project after the design phase?

Tags: unity, blender, project-management

I want to start a new project but I'm a beginner. I already have most of the ideas in terms of gameplay, lore,... I have written pages of notes and concepts about the game. Basically, I know most of the things I want to put in my game and a big part of their design is done.

I made a few small projects with Unity, I know how to program, I know how to use Blender and I have edited some textures. Basically, I know the basis most of the technologies I'll need to use.

The problem is that I don't know where to begin. Should I start with modelling? Create maps? Start with scripting? I'm undecided because many of these tasks can be done in parallel if you have people working with you and are more or less independent in early stages of development.

All of the answers I read were for people who didn't even have ideas in the first place and knew nothing about development. My problem is more about project management after the design phase.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What should be created first in a video game?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/130499/what-should-be-created-first-in-a-video-game)

Comment: Although there are useful tips in this post, it still doesn't quite answer my question. Suggesting to iterate on a small working prototype is good, but this is what I planned to do initially.

Comment: I can sort of see that argument, I suppose, but even the question isn't a duplicate it's still off topic here. Short of significantly editing your question to ask something more focused and objective -- which ultimately may save the question but not actually _help you_ -- I think you should try asking this on a more discussion-oriented forum like [GDNet](http://www.gamedev.net).

Comment: I agree that as worded, this is way off topic, but to help you out, what you're really asking is what are the steps in a Software Development Process. The phases tend to be the same, but differ in how you move from phase to phase depending on the methodology you choose. Agile, Waterfall, SCRUM, etc are all different Methodologies. Have a look at the [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_development_process) to get a better idea of which pattern you prefer and what it entails. Pay special attention to the 'Practices' section.

Comment: I'm a developper, so I have some skills regarding project management and coding habits, but I would like to hear advice from seasoned developpers. There must be one or multiple good ways to develop, and I would like to know them. Sure, not every one will agree on which one to choose and it is a bit opinion related, but all these methods are (or should be) objective steps and I would like to know them or at least know their names.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you have everything planned out, it think it's fair to say you can work on a proof-of-concept setup. make a test-map and character, and see if you can get most of the basic functionality to work. Try to work as modular as possible, so you can more easily scale your project and make changes.

Comment: For example, creating a player and creating functionalities like weapon mechanics? All of that using place-holder models? Would you suggest to focus on the functional aspect and then take care of the "artistic" aspect once the functional is done?

Comment: its always interesting to create a simple model with a rig, just to test something. it doesn't have to be pretty, but you have to make sure you get all transformations correct etc... you could indeed make something like weapon mechanics, collectibles, a simple navigation system etc.
This way, if you write a script to control the player that you can just swap on any character, you don't have to really worry about that later, and you can make modifications as much as you like. try to make prefabs, this will help you in the long run

Comment: tip: Something i like to do, is to use the standard thirdpersoncharacter that's included in unity, set it up the way i like it, and afterwards, if everything works, I import it into blender, and make a new mesh for the body. This way, i can save the entire setup as a prefab, and when i'm satisfied, i can update that prefab with another mesh, or change it in the code.

Comment: it might be better to make your models first.